# HTML entities in attributes with tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

When I have doble marks encoded in my HTML attributes, tinymce breaks that attributes.

For example:
`data-value="ab&quote;----&quote;">` will be seen in source code: `<div data-type="more-posts" data-value="ab">Hello</div>`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKYrbJ

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you would have real double quotes here your HTML would not be valid anymore because attributes use them.

It will be best do handle those when you save that content to your database.
You could replace them with single quotes - those wouldn't break the markup.